# How to configure timeout in expect script with Cygwin?

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin, expect

I am transferring some files using sftp. My source system is a ubuntu system while the destination is windows. And I have installed Cygwin software in windows for sftp and ssh. I have    the script as follows...

```
# FILE: test1.exp

set sftp_HOST somehost
set sftp_user someuser
set sftp_password somepassword
spawn sftp $sftp_user@$ftp_HOST
expect "*Password:* "
send "$sftp_password\r"
expect "sftp>* "
send "cd files\r"
expect "sftp>* "
send "mput *.xlsm\r"
expect "sftp>* "
send "quit\n"
expect eof
```

This script works fine. but at the middle some files not transferred properly. Due to timeout, other command continues from my shell script.

I am calling the above expect from below script...

```
# FILE: testscript.sh

export TELNET_PATH="/home/ist/Desktop/shellfilesscript"
expect $TELNET_PATH/test1.exp
cp *.xlsm /testfolder
```

For example, when running the test1.exp the cp command starts automatically and interrupts the expect command. I can't find any solution from previous posts, I think there is some        different way for cygwin. Help is appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: That's an unnecessarily complicated way of transferring files. The most practical way to transfer files would be to set up SSH keys so there's no need to enter passwords and then simply use scp or rsync to transfer the files. Your time will be better spent researching SSH keys than debugging SFTP with expect commands.

Comment: I am not only transferring files, but also i am running an vbscript on remote system. The script does some file processing there, but while processing it times out.

Answer (score 0):

To have an "infinite" timeout: `set timeout -1`

Comment: I tested the script by setting timeout -1. but after login it hangs for that specified time. In case of -1 it hangs for indefinite time.

Comment: add `exp_internal 1` after `spawn`, and the verbose debug output will show you why it's failing to match the first `expect`